# How to read an integers numbers individually

Tags: java

Hello guys I have a quick question. So I have an assignment where I have to create a program that recursively calculates the sum of all the digits in an integer. IE integer 123 (1+2+3) = 6.
How do I make it start at the first number and keep going until there is no other number left?
This is what i have so far....

```
import java.util.*;

public class sum 
{    
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
        System.out.println(sumDigits(123))   
    }

    public static  int sumDigits(int n)
    {
        while (n.hasNext())
        {
            return n.charAt(n.length) + sumDigits(n.charAt((n.length - 1)))
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know I'm using (hasNext and charAt which i'm not supposed to...) but what is the equivalent for the int?

Comment: There is no equivalent. The most obvious choice is to convert it to a String and do it like you're thinking. But if you're not allowed to do it like that, see comment by @nhahtdh

Comment: Nope, just modulo 10 and add it up.

Comment: @kayaman I am allowed to do that, I just meant its not valid with an int

Comment: @DavidCamacho That's why you convert the int into a String first. Although you state that you need to _recursively_ do this, so maybe modulo 10 is what they're after.

Comment: @nhahtdh how do I make it stop though?

Comment: @Kayaman: I don't know why you would convert it to String. Yes it is inline with OP's thinking, but the String conversion is a roundabout way to do the problem.

Comment: @DavidCamacho: If input can be negative, then you need to reverse the sign. Just stop when the leftover is 0.

Comment: n.hasNext() does int having hasNext() Method?

Comment: public static  int sumDigits(int n)
 {
  
  return (n % 10) + sumDigits(n % 10);
 }

Comment: @Ashok: Of course not. This is just OP's improvisational code

Comment: @DavidCamacho: You are up for stack overflow.

Comment: return (n%10) + sumDigits(n/10);

But still can't figure out how to stop it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple recursive solution:  you start from the end of your number and on each step you get the last digit of your number (which is `m`) and your number divided by 10, which is `next`. If on some step you got 0 as a result of `n / 10` - then it's the end of recursion, you can return your remainder. Otherwise you call your function again with `next`.

```
public static  int sumDigits(int n)
{
    int m = n % 10, next = n / 10;
    if (next == 0) {
        return m;
    }
    return m + sumDigits(next);
}
```

Comment: more concise than mine!

Comment: so is there an imaginary 0 at beginning of the integer?

Answer (score 5):

There are two operations you will need:

getting the last digit of a number: `n % 10`

getting a number without the last digit: `n / 10`

Using these two operations in a loop will get you all the digits of the number.

Comment: @DavidCamacho so you used a recursion; stop it when the number is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using recursion:

```
public int sumDigits(int n) {
    int abs = Math.abs(n), lastdigit = 0, sum = 0;
    if(n != 0) {
        lastdigit = abs % 10;
        sum = lastdigit + sumDigits(abs / 10);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

here some testeing:

```
@Test
public void sumDigits() {
    Assert.assertEquals(3, sumDigits(12));
    Assert.assertEquals(6, sumDigits(123));
    Assert.assertEquals(10, sumDigits(1234));
    Assert.assertEquals(15, sumDigits(12345));
    Assert.assertEquals(21, sumDigits(123456));
    Assert.assertEquals(28, sumDigits(1234567));
    Assert.assertEquals(28, sumDigits(7654321));
    Assert.assertEquals(28, sumDigits(-7654321));
    Assert.assertEquals(44, sumDigits(2056239854));
    Assert.assertEquals(46, sumDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // 2147483647
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*1st way :*

```
public static int sumDigits(int n) {                
            int validate = n % 10;
            int digit = n / 10;
            if (validate == 0) 
                return validate;
            return validate + sumDigits(digit);
        }
```

*2nd Way :*

```
public static int sumDigits(int n) {    
            String[] temp = Integer.toString(n).split("");
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++)// i=1 to skip first first empty value
                sum += Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);    
            return sum;   
         }
```

*Test:*

```
System.out.println("" + sumDigits(123)); // For both cases same O/p
```

*Output:*

```
6
```

Comment: Wait, why `Integer.valueOf(n).toString()` instead of just `Integer.toString(n)`?

Answer (score 0):

How to do a problem recursively

Think about the base case: if the num<10, then we just want to return that digit

What are the other cases? In this case, there is only one other case: we have more digits and we need to add the first digit and then process the rest

```
public int sumDigits(int n){
     return sumDigitsHelper(n,0);
}

public int sumDigitsHelper(int n, int sum){
     if(n<10)
          return sum+n;
     return sumDigitsHelper(n/10,sum+n%10);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, missed the requirement for being recursive.

```
public static int sumDigits(int n) {
  int sum = sumDigits0(n, 0);
  if (sum < 10) {
    return sum;
  }
  return sumDigits(sum);
}

private static int sumDigits(int n, int sum) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return sum;
  }
  return sumDigits(n/10, sum + (n%10));
}
```

Comment: The assignment said that he must find a recursive solution